# Tab Stop inside a choice for snippets in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am creating a bunch of snippets to make CNC programming easier using VS Code. I have some cases where I need to select between two choices like so: `Z-0.2` OR `Z [ -1. - 0.2 ]` where the `-1.` is a variable and can be any given number. Is there a way to create a placeholder within a snippet option so that when I select the 2nd option that my cursor will be at the place of where the `-1.` is?

Answer (score 0):

Snippet variables take the form of `$n` in the body of the snippet definition, where `n` is an integer (e.g., `$1`). You can use `${n:placeholder}` to provide a default value for a variable. `$` variables are tab-accessible ordered by `n`—except `$0`, which always comes last and exits snippet mode with the cursor at the specified position.

See: [Create your own snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets)